# JavaScript/TypeScript: count duplicate Objects in an Array of Objects to have an amount property on Item

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, object

So I have an array of items. There are duplicate items in that array and I am trying to count these duplicates. The count of those duplicates should be put into one of the duplicate items and the other item should be discarded.

### My input:

(simplified)

```json
[
  {
    "id": "fishing_rod",
    "emoji": "",
    "description": "Used to go fishing.",
    "category": "fishing",
  },
  {
    "id": "fishing_rod",
    "emoji": "",
    "description": "Used to go fishing.",
    "category": "fishing",
  },
  {
    "id": "pickaxe",
    "emoji": "⛏️",
    "description": "Used to go mining.",
    "category": "mining",
  },
],
```

### What I'm looking for:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "fishing_rod",
    "emoji": "",
    "description": "Used to go fishing.",
    "category": "fishing",
    "amount": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "pickaxe",
    "emoji": "⛏️",
    "description": "Used to go mining.",
    "category": "mining",
    "amount": 1
  },
]
```

### What I tried so far:

I have tried a few things but couldn't get there.

I've only gotten so far that I was able to only get the Item Id and the count. That looked a like this:

```js
const itemsArray = items.map((i) => i.id); // items being my input array (see top of this post)
const itemsUnique = [...new Set(itemsArray)];
const itemsCount = itemsUnique.map((item) => [item, itemsArray.filter((i) => i === item).length])
```

Output:

```json
[
  [ "fishing_rod", 2 ],
  [ "pickaxe", 1 ],
]
```

But that's not really what I am looking for...
A little help would be appreciated. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `filter` to remove the duplicates, at the same time incrementing the count.

```js
const input = [{"id": "fishing_rod","emoji": "","description": "Used to go fishing.","category": "fishing",},{"id": "fishing_rod","emoji": "","description": "Used to go fishing.","category": "fishing",},{"id": "pickaxe","emoji": "⛏️","description": "Used to go mining.","category": "mining",}]

const output = input.filter((val, i, arr) => {
  const first = arr.findIndex(({ id }) => val.id === id)
  if(first === i)
    return val.amount = 1 // the current value is the first occurence
  else arr[first].amount++ // the current value is not the first occurence
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over and group those with the same `id`:

(A terser version can be found in the snippet below.)

```js
function mergeItems(items) {
  const grouped = items.reduce((record, item) => {
    if (Object.hasOwn(record, item.id)) {
      record[item.id].count++;
    } else {
      record[item.id] = { ...item, count: 1 };
    }
    return record;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(grouped);
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function mergeItems(items) {
  const grouped = items.reduce((record, item) => {
    record[item.id] ??= { ...item, count: 0 };
    record[item.id].count++;
    return record;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(grouped);
}

const input = [
  {
    "id": "fishing_rod",
    "emoji": "",
    "description": "Used to go fishing.",
    "category": "fishing",
  },
  {
    "id": "fishing_rod",
    "emoji": "",
    "description": "Used to go fishing.",
    "category": "fishing",
  },
  {
    "id": "pickaxe",
    "emoji": "⛏️",
    "description": "Used to go mining.",
    "category": "mining",
  },
];

console.log(mergeItems(input));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically a one-liner :)

```js
const source = [
  {
    "id": "fishing_rod",
    "emoji": "",
    "description": "Used to go fishing.",
    "category": "fishing",
  },
  {
    "id": "fishing_rod",
    "emoji": "",
    "description": "Used to go fishing.",
    "category": "fishing",
  },
  {
    "id": "pickaxe",
    "emoji": "⛏️",
    "description": "Used to go mining.",
    "category": "mining",
  },
];

const result = {};
source.forEach((item) => result[item.id] ? result[item.id].amount ++ : result[item.id] = { ...item, amount: 1});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```